# How to assign 1D array to a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 1D array `A[3]` & a 2D array `B[4][3]`. I want to assign the array `A[3]` to one of the rows of array `B[4][3]`. How to do it correctly?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
   int A[3]={1,2,3};
   int B[4][3]={0};
   int row_select=2;

   B[row_select][] = A;
}
```

But this assignment doesn't work. I don't want to assign element by element using a for loop. I want to do it in one statement.

Comment: `memcpy` would be a good option.

Comment: You can't assign arrays directly.  Since you don't want to assign element by element, you'll have to use assignment 'byte by byte' with `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.  The functions probably won't do byte copying, but that's how they're specified.  (You can assign arrays indirectly if they're part of a structure; that wouldn't help you in this case, though.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. You could define a throwaway structure containing an array of the right size and nothing else, do some pointer casting, and probably get away with it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Hmmm; not sure how you're going to get the last row of `B` into an appropriate structure, or union.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler unless I'm missing your original point, it won't work: https://ideone.com/pH1hS2, https://ideone.com/IQ6ttg

Comment: @MadPhysicist — You could use `*b = *a;` in your examples to assign the structures without getting the assignment errors, but I think you're running into strict aliassing problems instead.  It's certainly devious, and not the sort of thing to show to someone asking this question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist "Probably get away with it" line of thinking and C language don't really go well together...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. I've posted an answer despite your excellent advice :)

Comment: @hyde. While I generally agree with you while coding, I've posted a valid counterexample, for a sufficiently loose definition of "valid" of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memcpy` could be a good option, although it's very likely it uses a loop internally.

```
memcpy(B[row_select], A, sizeof(A));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Do This: Use `memcpy`**

There is a way to do the assignment with a single statement, as long as you are willing to do some preliminary setup to render your code illegible. Your can use the fact that structures can (1) be assigned to each other in one step, and (2) contain fixed-size arrays. The compiler will probably run `memcpy` under the hood anyway, but it's a fun exercise in ridiculousness:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SZ 3 // this is just for convenience

// a pointer to an anonymous structure containing our array
typedef struct {
    int x[SZ];
} *pthrowaway;

int main(void)
{
    int A[SZ]={1,2,3};
    int B[4][SZ]={0};
    int row_select=2;

    pthrowaway a = (pthrowaway)&A;
    pthrowaway b = (pthrowaway)&B[row_select];

    *b = *a; // magic

    return 0;
}
```

The variables `a` and `b` are unnecessary. You can actually assign the arrays in a single statement:

```
*(pthrowaway)&B[row_select] = *(pthrowaway)&A;
```

Here is an IDEOne link showing the C99 version: https://ideone.com/IQ6ttg
And here is a regular C one: https://ideone.com/pH1hS2

Comment: Which is 'regular C'?  C11/C18?  Or C90?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. Whatever IDEOne uses. So GCC 6.3, which probably doesn't conform to any of those.

Comment: IIRC, you (the IDEOne site) uses GCC 6.x, and GCC 6.x treats C11 (effectively C18) as the default (and the change was at GCC 5.x; prior to that, the default was C90 — so poor old C99 never got to be the default version of the standard for GCC).  (A quick check of the GCC releases confirms my memory isn't ailing too much — https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html has the change to C11 as the top item, and GCC 5.1 was released in April 2015.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. As far as I'm aware this syntax was available for a long time, possibly before 89. I'm on a mobile platform, and lazy, so IDEOne is my idea of "checking what works".

Comment: @Nate. It's probably not. But why?

Comment: The syntax is fine in C90, as well as C99, C11, C18. The semantics could be straying into problems because the memory is being accessed by different pointer types and the compiler is entitled to assume no aliassing because neither type is a variant of `char *`. Whether a compiler can actually find a way to screw it up is open to debate, but optimizing compilers take delight in doing the damnedest things because of the strict aliassing rules — so it's playing with fire. Most likely you won't get burnt; neither in all probability will the OP. But someone coming across this and applying it might.

Comment: Well, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule, and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type, I don't think `int[3]` and `pthrowaway` are compatible types.  Indeed, there seems to be no way an array and a struct can ever be compatible types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. I did put a disclaimer at the top for that exact reason. At the same time, is there a sequence of casts that would make this more robust?

Comment: I see the "Don't do this" disclaimer.  It is probably sufficient — but people have very poor reading skills. I am not sufficiently sure of the interpretation of strict aliasing rules to know whether there are cast sequences that exempt the code from strict aliasing problems.  I _think_ that there aren't such casting sequences, but I don't _know_ for sure.  My thinking is that it depends on the types used to access the data, and simply casting via `char *` does not avoid the problem that the arrays are not the same a the structure containing an array. However, I might need to be educated on it.

Comment: @Nate. Reading through the link, they can through a union. I'll add that in tomorrow morning.

Comment: Beware the example 3 in C11 [§6.5.2.3 Structure and union members](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p9).  I'm not entirely sure how to interpret that either — be cautious.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I don't see how the union will help, unless the arrays are already in a union.  If you want to be sure of writing something legal, you may want to ask a new [tag:language-lawyer] question.